# Recursively remove 'parent' property based on child's condition

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, javascript-objects

I have an access JSON object like below

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Self Service",
      "data": {
        "roles": [
          "Employee",
          "Manager",
          "System Administrator"
        ]
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "Attendance",
          "icon": "pi pi-file",
          "data": {
            "roles": [
              "Employee",
              "System Administrator"
            ]
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Clocking",
              "icon": "pi pi-file",
              "data": {
                "roles": [
                  "Employee",
                  "System Administrator"
                ],
                "routerLink": ["ESS-ATT-clocking"]
              }
            },
            {
              "label": "History",
              "icon": "pi pi-file",
              "data": {
                "roles": [
                  "Employee",
                  "System Administrator"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "label": "Claim",
          "icon": "pi pi-file",
          "data": {
            "roles": [
              "Manager",
              "System Administrator"
            ]
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Entitlement & Request",
              "icon": "pi pi-file",
              "data": {
                "roles": [
                  "Manager",
                  "System Administrator"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

stored in a variable accessCtrl. I have another variable

```
role = "Employee"
```

Each child node is connected with "children" property.
How can i loop through (recursively) to remove the whole JSON object, "accessCtrl" and remove the particular node, if the "role" is not exists in data.role array?

e.g.

```
role = "Manager"
```

the object should return

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "label": "Self Service",
      "data": {
        "roles": [
          "Employee",
          "Manager",
          "System Administrator"
        ]
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "label": "Claim",
          "icon": "pi pi-file",
          "data": {
            "roles": [
              "Manager",
              "System Administrator"
            ]
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "label": "Entitlement & Request",
              "icon": "pi pi-file",
              "data": {
                "roles": [
                  "Manager",
                  "System Administrator"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

This is my current code and it doesn't seems work correctly.

```
function removeNode(obj, parent) {
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (
      prop === "data" &&
      prop.hasOwnProperty("roles") &&
      !prop.roles.includes(this.role)
    ) {
      if (parent) {
        delete parent.children;
      }
    } else if (typeof obj[prop] === "object") removeNode(obj[prop], obj);
  }
}

removeNode(this.accessCtrl, null);
console.log("this.accessCtrl=", this.accessCtrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function to be recursive, it needs to call itself.
Please let me know if you need more explanation on how it works.

```js
const input = {
  "data": [{
    "label": "Self Service",
    "data": {
      "roles": [
        "Employee",
        "Manager",
        "System Administrator"
      ]
    },
    "children": [{
      "label": "Attendance",
      "icon": "pi pi-file",
      "data": {
        "roles": [
          "Employee",
          "System Administrator"
        ]
      },
      "children": [{
        "label": "Clocking",
        "icon": "pi pi-file",
        "data": {
          "roles": [
            "Employee",
            "System Administrator"
          ],
          "routerLink": ["ESS-ATT-clocking"]
        }
      },
        {
          "label": "History",
          "icon": "pi pi-file",
          "data": {
            "roles": [
              "Employee",
              "System Administrator"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
      {
        "label": "Claim",
        "icon": "pi pi-file",
        "data": {
          "roles": [
            "Manager",
            "System Administrator"
          ]
        },
        "children": [{
          "label": "Entitlement & Request",
          "icon": "pi pi-file",
          "data": {
            "roles": [
              "Manager",
              "System Administrator"
            ]
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}

const role = "Manager";

const removeRoles = (tree, role) => {
  const newTree = []
  for (const item of tree) {
    if (item.data.roles.includes(role)) {
      if (item.children) {
        item.children = removeRoles(item.children, role) // this is where it gets recursive
      }
      newTree.push(item)
    }
  }
  return newTree;
}

const result = { data: removeRoles(input.data, role) }

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would separate out the code that filters your recursive array from the actual code that tests the business requirement (here that's `({data: {roles}}) => roles .includes ('Manager')`.)  Here's one possibility:

```js
const filterDeep = (pred) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (x => pred (x)
    ? [{... x, children: filterDeep (pred) (x .children || [])}] 
    : []
  )

const justManagers = (({data, ...rest}) => ({
  ...rest,
  data: filterDeep (({data: {roles}}) => roles .includes ('Manager')) (data)
}))

const input = {data: [{label: "Self Service", data: {roles: ["Employee", "Manager", "System Administrator"]}, children: [{label: "Attendance", icon: "pi pi-file", data: {roles: ["Employee", "System Administrator"]}, children: [{label: "Clocking", icon: "pi pi-file", data: {roles: ["Employee", "System Administrator"], routerLink: ["ESS-ATT-clocking"]}}, {label: "History", icon: "pi pi-file", data: {roles: ["Employee", "System Administrator"]}}]}, {label: "Claim", icon: "pi pi-file", data: {roles: ["Manager", "System Administrator"]}, children: [{label: "Entitlement & Request", icon: "pi pi-file", data: {roles: ["Manager", "System Administrator"]}}]}]}]}

console .log (
  justManagers (input)
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`filterDeep` does the recursive tree walking and includes only those nodes that match our predicate.  `justManager` does a little juggling of the input structure so that we can focus only on the `data` property and then calls `filterDeep` passing it our predicate that tests whether our node has the "Manager" role.  It leaves any other properties of our input data intact.

Comment: i am not into the position to judge the efficiency of the code (as it's too much for a intermediate coder). @Scott you are Ninja! But i decided to for the first solution as i might having hardtime maintain your code. it's too advanced for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). We use object-scan for our data processing, but it does take a moment to wrap your head around. Conceptually the solution is simple: We check "leaf first" and then work up the hierarchy and delete if (1) no children are present and (2) desired role is not present

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const input = { data: [{ label: 'Self Service', data: { roles: ['Employee', 'Manager', 'System Administrator'] }, children: [{ label: 'Attendance', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: ['Employee', 'System Administrator'] }, children: [ { label: 'Clocking', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: ['Employee', 'System Administrator'], routerLink: ['ESS-ATT-clocking'] } }, { label: 'History', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: ['Employee', 'System Administrator'] } } ] }, { label: 'Claim', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: ['Manager', 'System Administrator'] }, children: [ { label: 'Entitlement & Request', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: ['Manager', 'System Administrator'] } } ] }] }] };

const prune = (role, data) => objectScan(['{data,**.children}[*]'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, property, parent }) => {
    if (
      !value.data.roles.includes(role)
      && (value.children || []).length === 0
    ) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data);

console.log(prune('Manager', input)); // return number of deletions
// => 3
console.log(input);
/* => { data: [
  {
    label: 'Self Service',
    data: { roles: [ 'Employee', 'Manager', 'System Administrator' ] },
    children: [
      { label: 'Claim', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: [ 'Manager', 'System Administrator' ] }, children: [
        { label: 'Entitlement & Request', icon: 'pi pi-file', data: { roles: [ 'Manager', 'System Administrator' ] } }
      ] }
    ]
  }
] } */
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)